# Difference between bin files that are executed via ./binfile and "regular" bins?

Tags: executable, bin

I built a C program using `make` on Ubuntu. The resulting bin file is executeable via `./binfilename` but not by just executing it in the directory it was build. 
How can i "convert" it to a bin file that I can copy to `/usr/bin` so I can execute it "system-wide" or does this require a different build process?

Answer (score 5):

This is not because there is a difference between the binaries but because the directory the binary is in is not in your `PATH`.

On Windows the current directory is always part of your `PATH`.  However this is not secure (imagine someone placing a copy of `rm` named `ls` in some directory).

So you need to either place the binary in one of the directories in your `PATH` (see `echo $PATH`) or you have to add that particular directory to yuor `PATH`.  e.g. by adding something like

PATH="$PATH:/home//bin"

to your `~/.bash_rc`.

Comment: Damm, o.k., that was easy :)